# "To believe the ocean exists when you see a stream. it is the vision ..."

Tags: grammar, expressions

Is this grammatically correct?

Please correct the above quote.

I want to complete the expression.

Comment: Hi Eugene! It isn't really a *grammar* problem. “To believe the ocean exists when you see a stream” doesn't make sense. It is an incomplete sentence because the verb is in the infinitive form. "To eat" is not a complete sentence: it doesn't make sense. "I am eating" IS a complete sentence and DOES make sense.